# How do I enable the PostgreSQL function profiler?

Tags: postgresql, function, profiling, plpgsql

This took me a while to figure out and I found the answer on a foreign-language wiki a number of weeks ago, and it was very helpful, so I thought I would share.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On PostgreSQL 8.3 on Win32, the profiling plugin is installed by default, but not loaded.  Just execute this SQL:

```
LOAD '$libdir/plugins/plugin_profiler.dll';
SET plpgsql.profiler_tablename = 'bazzybar';
```

...and then when you want to profile some code,

```
drop table if exists bazzybar; -- reset the profiling stats
select my_function_here('lala',123);  -- this line and variations as many times as you deem fit
select * from bazzybar; -- show the time spent on each line of your function
```