# How to profile plpgsql function in PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: performance, postgresql, profiling, plpgsql

I'd like to find the bottlenecks in a plpgsql function, so I'm looking for a profiler.

[How do I enable the PostgreSQL function profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430123/how-do-i-enable-the-postgresql-function-profiler) suggests loading the `plugin_profiler.dll` library, but it was written for 8.3 and there seems to be no such thing in 9.2

I've also installed and the debugger described at http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=pldebugger.git;a=summary (which is included with 9.2), but can't see any way of using it as a profiler.

The simple "RAISE NOTICE" method wouldn't be effective for me, because the function executes in < 0.1 ms, but is called many times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PostgreSQL 9.2 has buildin SQL profiler, try to use it - if your plpgsql contains some SQL queries.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/pgstatstatements.html

and now, [plpgsql_check](https://github.com/okbob/plpgsql_check) has integrated profiler

Comment: Thanks, this is quite useful together with `pg_stat_user_functions`